How can I configure assetPrefix in React similar to Next.js?
In Next.js, we have the ability to adjust the assetPrefix to modify the prefix for JavaScript and CSS files within the build files (Next assetPrefix). Is there a comparable method to achieve this in a standard React project?
To be clear, I want to change the generated index.html from displaying: 
To instead display something like this: 
I'm trying to find a similar configuration, but I'm unable to locate it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
